# why array data is not working on php magic method __call()?

Tags: php, oop

Here is a variable and it's output is following :

```
$a = [2, 3, 4];  
echo implode(',', $a);
```

**Output**

```
2,3,4
```

**And**

I have a class with a php magic method `__call`

```
class MagicMethod {

    public function __call ( $pm, $values ) {
        echo "there is not <b>$pm</b> method <br/> and arguments are <br/>";
        echo implode(',', $values);
    }
}

$magic =  new MagicMethod;    
$magic->notExist( [2, 3, 54] );
```

**Now** it's showing me error message :

> Notice: Array to string conversion in

Why is the `__call` method getting array data?

Comment: Because you give it an array? ( **[2, 3, 54]**
 => thats an array ). And afterwards you try to `echo` the array, which then results in the "Array to string conversion..."

Comment: Because you're passing a single argument, which happens to be an array; so inside __call(), it's `$values[0]`.... use `echo implode(',', $values[0]);` inside your `__call()` method

Comment: php `implode()` function need `array` data of it's 2nd arguments and I did it !!

Comment: @Xatenev I echo the array with `implode` function !

Comment: echo implode(',', $values);

Answer (score 3):

Second argument of `__call()` is an array of all arguments that were passed to the method.

From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call):

> The $name argument is the name of the method being called. The $arguments argument is an enumerated array containing the parameters passed to the $name'ed method.

In your case `$values` would be:

```
[
    [2, 3, 54]
]
```

What you are doing is calling `implode()` on this array, which results in a *Array to string conversion* error because `[2, 3, 54]` cannot be converted to a string.

Answer (score 0):

$values in __call method is array of arguments passed in notExist method.

So array passed in notExist method will be accessed by $values[0].

See following code.

```
class MagicMethod {

    public function __call ( $pm, $values ) {
        echo "there is not <b>$pm</b> method <br/> and arguments are <br/>";
        echo implode(',', $values[0]);
    }
}

$magic =  new MagicMethod;    
$magic->notExist( [2, 3, 54] );
```